How to include NAs in graph (disconnected graph) for grouped data?
I am trying to print a line graph with ggplot2.  My data has missing values and I tried adding NAs but the ggplot does not show a gap for missing data. I looked in stackoverflow for similar questions and the solutions work, however in my case, there is a grouping and this causes the line graph to no longer work by connecting missing data rather than leaving gaps.  Does anyone have ideas other than for me to edit the graph in a graphics software?
salary <- c(10000,25000,90000,15000,85000,
        65000,67000,23000,75000,35000,
        90000,65000,52000,52000,100000)
district <- c('A','A','A','A','A',
          'B','B','B','B','B',
          'E','E','E','E','E')
year <- c(1985,1986,1987,1990,1991,  # Missing data for 1988 and 1989
      1985,1986,1987,1990,1991,
      1985,1986,1987,1990,1991)

dat <- data.frame(salary, district, year)

# aggregate data by year and district
g <- aggregate(salary ~ year + district, 
            data = dat, 
            FUN = sum) 

# add NAs to see if it will work but does not
g[nrow(g) + 1,] = c(NA,'A',1988)
g[nrow(g) + 1,] = c(NA,'B',1988)
g[nrow(g) + 1,] = c(NA,'E',1988)
g[nrow(g) + 1,] = c(NA,'A',1989)
g[nrow(g) + 1,] = c(NA,'B',1989)
g[nrow(g) + 1,] = c(NA,'E',1989)

ggplot(g, aes(x=year, y=salary, group=district)) +
geom_line(aes(linetype=district), size = 0.65)+
geom_point(size = 0.5)+ 
xlab("Year") + 
ylab("Salary") +
scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid","dashed")) +
scale_linetype_discrete(name="District") +  
theme_bw() 




The columns of g are year, district, and salary, but your added rows seem to have salary first, which is like dat instead of g. I'm unclear on what g is meant to accomplish when its data is the same (before the NA steps) as dat, just different column order.

Thanks for catching that, I updated my code.  If I use dat or g as a data source, the graph does not display any gaps.  I need the gaps to appear to inform the audience the data is missing.

I think the issue is with your step adding NA's. When I formulate the data using the following code, I get breaks in the chart series as desired. g <- aggregate(salary ~ year + district,  data = dat, FUN = sum) |> dplyr::bind_rows( data.frame(year = rep(c(1988, 1989), each = 3),district = c("A","B","E")))

In your code where you intend to add NAs, you add rows as vectors, and vectors must be of one type, so they are coerced to character, and that cascades to the entirety of every column, so your NA salaries (assuming you adjust your code to have the new rows match the column order of g) become "NA" salaries, which as character data can be plotted along with "10000" and so do not result in gaps.

That worked thank you but for my understanding (and others reading this) if I add the 6 NA's this way then aggregate with my aggregate code, why doesn't this method of adding NA work? : dat<- rbind(dat, data.frame(salary=NA, district="A", year = 1988))
